# Google Authentication with Dynamodb instead of mongoose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, passport-google-oauth2

I have been following [this tutorial](https://github.com/BrentAureli/Youtube-Tutorials/tree/master/NodeJS%20Tutorials/Tutorial%2011%20-%20Google%20OAuth) and it has given me great insight into linking up a mongodb and getting back google authentication. However, I want to use dynamodb, and I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-localhost) to hook up a localhost dynamodb to test out my theories, but I am not sure how to swap out mongoose - because I don't want it linking to a mongodb, or can I use mongoose for the schema and tell it to write to a dynamodb? Not sure. Thanks for any guidance in advance. I'm new to aws if you can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose is a library for connecting to MongoDB. I believe your question title should be "DynamoDB instead of MongoDB".

You can't use Mongoose to connect to DynamoDB. There are many differences between MongoDB and DynamoDB. If you want to use DynamoDB with your NodeJS application you should look into using the [AWS SDK for NodeJS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/).

Please be aware that there are major differences between MongoDB and DynamoDB. It's not going to be trivial to take a MongoDB tutorial and modify that to work with DynamoDB. I highly recommend you read up on DynamoDB and understand its restrictions and limitations before committing to using it.

Comment: That is what I thought, I was pretty sure I have to ditch mongoose in favor of something with dynamodb.  Do I need to use cognito in order to do google authentication instead of mongoose? I also saw a few npm modules that did a schema for dynamodb similar to mongoose, is that a road worth traveling, I don't see a lot written about it.

Comment: I've never used any of those NPM modules so I can't tell you if they are worth using. I'm pretty sure Mongoose wasn't doing google authentication, Passport was. Mongoose is just mapping your objects into MongoDB. You could use Cognito instead of Passport. It entirely depends on how you want to design your application.

Comment: Does passport have anything that integrates in with dynamodb? It keeps calling User.findOrCreate in the documentation, so I assume it is only used with mongodb.

Comment: Try searching and see what you find. I think it's pretty easy to wire up Passport to use any database.

Comment: well that is why I am commenting and posting, because I am not finding a lot of links that tell me how to use passport with dynamodb.

Comment: I would be doing the same searches you are. Are these top two hits on Google not helpful? https://gist.github.com/samuelhei/7371e62ae8f18e8811e6  and https://github.com/christianboutin/passportjs-dynamodb

Comment: Yes, I saw one of them before. Not a clear link to google, but yes it talks about the local connection. I will look into passportjs-dynamodb too. Thanks for your help.